# Uncaught in promise, failed to fetch when uploading file to AWS S3

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to upload files to S3, but am getting this error (I edited the name of the bucket). When putting in a try/catch block, I can  see the error is "access denied."

```
mockServiceWorker.js:130 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at mockServiceWorker.js:130:72
    at handleRequest (mockServiceWorker.js:135:7)
index.js:1227 
 POST https://name-of-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) 
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://name-of-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/', redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
[[Prototype]]: Headers
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "cors"
url: "https://name-of-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { postAdded } from './PostsSlice'
import S3 from 'react-aws-s3'

export function AddPostForm() {

//Removed

    const ReactS3Client = new S3(config)
    ReactS3Client.uploadFile(file, newFileName).then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      if (data.status === 204) {
        console.log('success')
      } else {
        console.log('fail')
      }
    })
  //Removed rest of code
}
```

This is the CORS policy I'm using for S3. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Does this have to do with CORS, or is it an issue with S3, or is there a syntax error? I checked that the bucket name is correct and the region.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:3000"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Comment: access denied in s3 or in your backend? also what's in your config for s3

Comment: First of all, if you use promisechaining (ie `.then()`) you should also have a `.catch()` somewhere (either directly with the promise, or somewhere up in the callstack, where you are waiting for this promise), which will prevent the "Uncaught promise ..." Second. There is not enough information, and that information is also inconsistent. You are saying you got an "Access Denied" error, yet your errormessage shows "Bad Request"  (or is this the same error?)

Comment: @Derpirscher When I run the code listed, I get "Bad Request." Someone else suggested I wrap it in a try/catch block, and when I do it shows a link, when I click it it only has 4 lines of code, two of which say "access denied" and the other two don't provide any relevant information.

Comment: @Nonik I'm not sure how to tell, I get access denied as the error when I wrap the S3 request in a try/catch block, so I'm pretty sure it's coming from S3. When you say my config, do you mean the bucket policy? If so this is it.

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policyxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmtxxxxxxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::name-of-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: no, i mean this config new S3(config), if it's s3 usually mean iam role is not correctly set up